# How to pass parameters to PowerShell script from batch file?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

This should be an easy syntax fix, I just could not wrap my mind around all the google searching suggestions.

The ps1 script does work when invoked from PowerShell terminal, I can pass all three parameters and receive the email.
When trying to run it from a batch file (cmd)

```
ShellScript:
# get parameters
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
        $recipients,
        $subject,
        $body
)
#$ParamSetName = $PsCmdLet.ParameterSetName
# send email
Send-MailMessage -From "noreply@snorepl.com" -To $recipients -Subject $subject -SmtpServer  'somesmtpserver.somedomain.com' -BODY $body
```

Batch script:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command "C:\scripts\send_email.ps1 -recipients '%recipients%' -subject '%subject%' -body '%body%'"
```

When calling the bath script I get the following error:

> The string is missing the terminator: '.
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordEx   ception
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString

Comment: Do any of the batch environment variables contain double quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `-File` parameter?

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\Scripts\send_email.ps1 -Recipients '%recipients%' -Subject '%subject%' -Body '%body%'
```

(Aside: If you insist on `-Command`, why do you need the script? Just run `Send-MailMessage` directly.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Bill, I am not sure what is the difference between -command and -File but I was able to pass the parameters, the script works fine if I only pass one email address, if I pass a second one separated by a comma then the script put it in parameter 2 (thinks the comma is a space?)the powershell works fine with comma separated emails

Comment: Remember that we can't see your screen. Update your question with what doesn't work and _how_ it doesn't work. Use copy and paste rather than screenshots.